# how to use EventToCommand in a ItemContainerStyle?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand, itemcontainerstyle

```
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DoubleClick" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

This is how it works now.
What should I do if I want to Bind every ListBoxItem's DoubleClick event to a RelayCommand?

Comment: can you provide some more info about `EventToCommand` feature?

Comment: @stukselbax : as one of the tags suggest, it's a class in mvvm-light.

Comment: Maybe this Q&A is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878362/mvvmlight-eventtocommand-and-wpftoolkit-datagrid-double-click

Comment: The EventToCommand in MVVM Light leaks memory. Don't use it in non-trivial applications.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: thanks for the heads up, is it a known issue?

Comment: Yes. Look at issue 7549: EventToCommand Non-determinisitically disables controls http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I am using the MVVMLight EventToCommand feature.

If you have a doubleclick event hook to that. If that is not available take the (preview)mousedown and check the clickCount in the command args. A ClickCount of 2 corresponds to a double click.

Please note: I have my own RelayCommand Implementation. The one from the MVMMLight toolkit might look different.

**XAML:**

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
        <mvvmLight:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding MouseDownCommand}"></mvvmLight:EventToCommand>
    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
</interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ICommand MouseDownCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (_mouseDownCommand == null)
    {
      _mouseDownCommand = new RelayCommand(x => MouseDown(x as MouseButtonEventArgs));
    }
    return _mouseDownCommand;
  }
}

private void MouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ClickCount == 2)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this is to just use a normal event handler written in code-behind. If needed this can relay to a method or command on your model or view-model.

Tricks like using an EventToCommand behavior just cost you in terms of more complex XAML and a pretty high risk that you will leak memory. (This happens because EventToCommand listens to the CanExecuteChanged event even when it shouldn't.)