# How to pass DataGridCellEditEventArgs in WPF MVVM Application

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, datagrid

I am working on WPF LOB application and Using Prism and delegate commands to separate UI from View Model.

When ever user make a change on a particular cell FROM UI (not from View Model or Service), I need to invoke some other functionality.

I have created the Attached Behavior

```
public static class DataGridCellEditEndingBehaviour
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty CellEditEndingProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CellEditEnding",
        typeof(CellEditEnding),
        typeof(DataGridCellEditEndingBehaviour),
        null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(DataGridCellEditEndingBehaviour),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandCallback));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
       "CommandParameter",
       typeof(object),
       typeof(DataGridCellEditEndingBehaviour),
       new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandParameterCallback));

    public static ICommand GetCommand(DataGrid control)
    {
        return control.GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
    }

    public static void SetCommand(DataGrid control, ICommand command)
    {
        control.SetValue(CommandProperty, command);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(DataGrid control, object parameter)
    {
        control.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, parameter);
    }

    public static object GetCommandParameter(DataGrid control)
    {
        return control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    private static void OnSetCommandCallback
        (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid control = dependencyObject as DataGrid;
        if (control != null)
        {
            CellEditEnding behavior = GetOrCreateBehavior(control);
            behavior.Command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
        }
    }

    private static void OnSetCommandParameterCallback
        (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid control = dependencyObject as DataGrid;
        if (control != null)
        {
            CellEditEnding behavior = GetOrCreateBehavior(control);
            behavior.CommandParameter = e.NewValue;
        }
    }

    private static CellEditEnding GetOrCreateBehavior(DataGrid control)
    {
        CellEditEnding behavior =
            control.GetValue(CellEditEndingProperty) as CellEditEnding;
        if (behavior == null)
        {
            behavior = new CellEditEnding(control);
            control.SetValue(CellEditEndingProperty, behavior);
        }
        return behavior;
    }
}

public class CellEditEnding : CommandBehaviorBase<DataGrid>
{
    public CellEditEnding(DataGrid control)
        : base(control)
    {
        control.CellEditEnding += OnCellEditEnding;
    }

    private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteCommand();
    }
}
```

And I am able to invoke the same using

```
local:DataGridCellEditEndingBehaviour.Command ="{Binding CellChangedCommand}"
```

1. When the event gets invoked, I don't get any eventargs in my delegateCommand in VM,  how I can retrieve the event args, can I set it through Command Parameters? If so, how can i pass the event args to delegate command?
2. During the CellEditEndigEvent, the value is not yet stored in to the VM as it is still in transition, is there a way I can force it to happen from the handler, so I don't need to read values from CellEditEndingEventArgs, instead I can read from VM directly?

Answer (score 0):

It's an attached property. You use it like
local:DataGridCellEditEndingBehaviour.CommandParameter="{Binding against whatever you want to pass}"

You have probably implement custom DataGrid which has custom property that indicates Cell that was edited or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this trying to solve a similar problem - in a MVVM app, we have a UserControl with a DataGrid and so we need to have the RowEditEnding event bind to a Command. I could not quite follow the example above, and could not determine how to find CommandBehaviorBase.

Partly based on the answer at [MvvmLight EventToCommand and WPFToolkit DataGrid double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878362/mvvmlight-eventtocommand-and-wpftoolkit-datagrid-double-click), I implemented our AttachedBehaviour as follows:

```
Public Class DataGridHelper
Public Shared ReadOnly RowEditEndingCommandProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RowEditEndingCommand",
                                        GetType(ICommand),
                                        GetType(DataGridHelper),
                                        New UIPropertyMetadata(AddressOf OnRowEditEnding))

Public Shared Sub SetRowEditEndingCommand(control As DataGrid, command As ICommand)
    control.SetValue(RowEditEndingCommandProperty, command)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnRowEditEnding(dependencyObject As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim control As DataGrid = TryCast(dependencyObject, DataGrid)
    If control Is Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("This behavior can be attached to a DataGrid item only.")
    End If

    If e.NewValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.OldValue Is Nothing Then
        AddHandler control.RowEditEnding, AddressOf RowEditEnding
    ElseIf e.NewValue Is Nothing AndAlso e.OldValue IsNot Nothing Then
        RemoveHandler control.RowEditEnding, AddressOf RowEditEnding
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Sub RowEditEnding(sender As Object, e As DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs)
    Dim element As UIElement = DirectCast(sender, UIElement)
    Dim command As ICommand = DirectCast(element.GetValue(DataGridHelper.RowEditEndingCommandProperty), ICommand)
    'command.Execute(Nothing)
    command.Execute(e)
End Sub
End Class
```

So far this seems to work, and appears simpler than the approach above. We pass the DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs back to the Command in the parameter, so it is available in the ViewModel. This will probably also work for the CellEditEnding event.